# Make multiple images fade in at different page positions jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I am trying to have an img fade in at a certain page position, then have another img fade in at a different page position... How can I achieve this, my code is below. Right now I only have it set for one img, can't figure out how to add a second one with different page position.

```
var startY = 20

$(window).scroll(function(){
checkY();
});

function checkY(){
if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
    $('#head_bar').fadeIn();
}else{
    $('#head_bar').fadeOut();
}
}

// Do this on load just in case the user starts half way down the page
checkY();
```

Comment: Can include `html` ?

Comment: just using it on these two images
<img id="header_img" src="img/home_header2.jpg" />
<img id="video_img" src="img/video_header" />

Comment: Are images initially `hidden` ? _"then have another img fade in at a different page position"_ ? Can describe  _"at a different page position"_ ?

Comment: I have the images as display none in my css. I'm a huge noob with jq so you may have to be specific for me to understand

Comment: First image would fade in at `startY` ? Second image would fade in at ? Does first image fade out when second image fades in ? Are images _only_ `html` within document ?

Comment: Yes first image fades in at startY second image I would like to fade in at about 70? I would have to see it with the design. First images does not fade out I need it to stay on the page while the others fade in.

Comment: Are images the _only_ `html` within document ?, no other elements ?

Comment: I have a lot of other elements, but they shouldn't interfere with the fadesins

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work, not sure if it's reliable, works on safari chrome and firefox...

```
var startY = 20
var startX = 170

$(window).scroll(function(){
checkY();
});

function checkY(){
if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
    $('#head_bar').fadeIn();
if($(window).scrollTop() > startX ) 
    $('#video_img').fadeIn();
}else{
    $('#head_bar').fadeOut();
    $('#video_img').fadeOut();

}
}
```